# How do I make unpushable commits pushable?

Tags: git, git-branch, git-push, git-commit

`Master` Branch had commits like this : `A -> B -> C(HEAD)` . `HEAD` was at `C`.

**What I did :**

I checked out `B` and made commits on top of it.

Now the tree looks like this :

```
    A -> B -> C(master)(origin/master)
         |
         | -> B1 -> B2(HEAD)
```

`git status` on the project directory is giving me the following message :

```
# Not currently on any branch.
nothing to commit (working directory clean)`
```

So it means that `B1` and `B2` cannot be pushed. I got to know that this is happening because these commits doesn't exist on any branch. Now, if I switch my branch back to master will these commits be lost? I am expecting a few more commits(`B3, B4 ... BN`) on these unnamed branch after which I want `C` to come on top of it. In essence, I would like to see the `master` branch in this way :

```
    A -> B -> B1 -> B2 -> B3 -------> BN -> C(master)(origin/master)
```

or atleast this way :

```
    A -> B ---------------------> C(master)(origin/master) -> D
         |                                                    ^
         |                                                    |
         | -> B1 -> B2 -> -> ...->BN--------------------------
```

What options I have to accomplish this? I want to be able to save the commits in the `origin`.

Any suggestions/directions is appreciated.

Comment: It would be helpful to know _why_ you want your commits in `origin`. Is it just for backup, or so someone else can see them, or something else?

Comment: Just backup. Actually the C commit is supposed to be made just before the release and problems popped up after I made C commit. So I had to checkout the previous commit and fix the problems. Not sure when the C commit will be merged, but it will be done just before the release.

Comment: So the choice of pushing the temp branch to `origin`, or merging to `master` and keeping the temp branch local, will depend on your workflow. If you definitely want to push the temp branch, let me know and I can add more detail to that section.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your desired outcome

```
A -> B -> B1 -> B2 -> B3 -------> BN -> C(master)(origin/master)
```

is not possible unless you can rewrite **C** in the remote repo; doing this would cause problems for everyone else who has done work based on **C**.

The second preference

```
A -> B ---------------------> C(master)(origin/master) -> D
     |                                                    ^
     |                                                    |
     | -> B1 -> B2 -> -> ...->BN--------------------------
```

is easy: as Magnus says, you'll make your life much easier if you give **B2** (or whatever is the current latest commit in your sequence) a branch name: this is just easier to remember and type than the hash, and will make sure it doesn't get garbage collected.

```
git checkout -b bbranch

A -> B -> C(master)(origin/master)
     |                                                    
     |                                                    
     | -> B1 -> B2 (bbranch)
```

Now, if you want to push **B1** and **B2** to origin for whatever reason, you can merge and push as normal

```
git checkout master
git pull
git merge bbranch

A -> B ------> C -> D (master)
     |             /
     |            /
     | -> B1 -> B2 (bbranch)

git push
```

You can *keep* working on **bbranch** and merge *again* when you're done with it

```
A -> B ------> C -> D -> E -> ... -> En -> F (master)
     |             /                      /
     |            /                      /
     | -> B1 -> B2 -> B3  ->  ...  -> Bn  (bbranch)
```

---

Note: if you want to push your commits to **origin** for whatever reason, but you *don't* want them on **master**, you can simply push **bbranch** and it'll take your commits with it. You'll then either need to be sure that no-one else will touch **bbranch**, or to make your local copy a remote-tracking branch.

Replace the merge step `B2 -> D` with `git push origin bbranch` in this case.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why you don't create a new branch for your commits. Here's what I would do:

```
git checkout B
git checkout -b fix
.. do some stuff
git commit -am 'did some stuff to B'
git checkout master
git merge fix
```

---

First answer:

```
git checkout master
git merge B2
```

Your commits are never ever lost, unless you clean up references to them (with git gc etc). As long as you have committed your changes, you are safe.

Comment: I want to merge only after I make the `BN` commit and I want to be able to save/push `B1...BN` commits.

Comment: git checkout master, git merge BN .. then your commits are on the master branch and you can push your master branch.

Comment: But the problem is the commit `BN` can happen after a week and I  want to save the commits `B1, B2 etc.,` by pushing it to the origin.

Comment: B1, B2 are not lost, they are still there. Just merge with their hash values. In the future make sure to create a new branch from B to simplify this.

Comment: Rewrote my answer. However, it's still possible to merge single commits made on no branch.

Answer (score 1):

What you are asking for, if I understand you correctly, is a way to make commits visible in an external repository *when they are not part of a branch*.

Commits B1 and B2 are accessible by their SHA1 hash, but not by any named ref. So, from git's perspective, they are "garbage" and will eventually be cleaned up by a `git gc` (after a sufficient period of time as defined by your settings has elapsed).

When you do a `git push`, it's pushing the changes which are "part of" your repository. This includes all changesets *accessible from a named ref*. The "garbage" commits don't go.

So, if you don't want the changes to be part of some *other* branch, but you still want to push them, you should make them a branch of their own. This will have the effect of allowing you to push them, giving you a handle to access them, and preventing them from being garbage collected (which you don't want).

If, on the other hand, you are ready to make the loose commits *part of* the `master` branch, you want `git rebase` (to put them atop the current `master`) or `git merge` (to integrate them with master while preserving the accurate history you currently have). You could also rewrite the `master` branch to include the commits as your "first" example, but I don't recommend this (especially if you already pushed `master` in another state).

To more explicitly answer your question "if I switch my `HEAD` back to `master`, will those commits be lost?", the answer is "eventually, yes, but immediately, no.". You can do a checkout of the explicit SHA1 IDs of the commits (and find those using `git reflog`, or the `HEAD@{1}` syntax). But in time they will go away if you don't attach a named ref to them.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. Is it possible to give the branch `B -> B1 -> B2` a name now and push it? or should I checkout `B`, create a new branch, merge `B1, B2` to the branch and then push it?

Comment: Yes, you can give the branch a name. `git checkout -b new_name B2` (using the SHA1 hash of `B2`) will create a `new_name` branch whose `HEAD` is `B2`. If you're already on `B2`, it's just `git branch new_name` instead of using the `checkout -b` method.

Answer (score 0):

Check git rebase with --interactive option.